# SASS keyframes not compiling as wanted

Tags: sass

I am using the following keyframes mixin for SCSS

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

it works perfectly, when i have to animate, which has the `animation` property, but when i try to use it for child elements i get not the output, that i need (but syntax-valid)

Example:

```
@include keyframes('text') {
    0% {
        span { color: red; }
    }
    100% {
        span { color: green; }
    }
}
```

Will output (**short ouput**):

```
@keyframes text {
    0% span { color: red; }
    100% span { color: green; }
}
```

But what i need is:

```
@keyframes text {
     0% {
        span { color: red; }
    }
     100% {
        span { color: green; }
    }
}
```

How can i prevent sass from snapping the first brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i am concerned you apply keyframes to an element. so your desired output:

```
@keyframes text {
     0% {
        span { color: red; }
    }
     100% {
        span { color: green; }
    }
}
```

does not make much sense in CSS.

I think what you need is something like :

```
@keyframes span#text {
    0% {color: red; }
    100% { color: green; }
}
```

also it is not your mixin problem as this SASS:

```
0% {
    span { color: red; }
}
100% {
    span { color: green; }
}
```

compiles to:

```
0%  span {
  color: red; }

100%  span {
  color: green; }
```

as desired.

I think the intended usege of your keyframes mixin would be something like:

```
span#text {

    @include keyframes(text) {
      0% {
        color: red;
      }
      100% {
        color: green;
      } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you :) realy didn't want to do it that way, but i guess i'll have to :c