# Sass Keyframes animation mixin generating invalid CSS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-animations

I have the following keyframes mixin, but it seems to be generated invalid CSS:

```
@mixin keyframes($animationName)
{
    @-webkit-keyframes $animationName {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes $animationName {
        @content;
    }
    @-o-keyframes $animationName {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes $animationName {
        @content;
    }
}

@include keyframes(icon-one) {
        0% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        33% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        66% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
@-webkit-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes $animationName {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Instead of having the keyframes name of `icon-one`, it's writing out `$animationName`.

Comment: Can you post the compiled CSS?

Comment: sorry thought sass was cleaner to work with, I've proceeded to remove sass and added pure css

Comment: wow thanks, everything looks crystal clear now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're required to use string interpolation on variables for keyframes names.  Your keyframes mixin needs to be written like this:

```
@mixin keyframes($animationName)
{
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$animationName} {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$animationName}  {
        @content;
    }
    @-o-keyframes #{$animationName} {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes #{$animationName} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Note that the [keyframes mixin that comes with Compass does this](https://github.com/Compass/compass/blob/stable/core/stylesheets/compass/css3/_animation.scss#L37).

There is an issue on GitHub that indicates that [interpolation was not required in certain versions of Sass (possibly limited to 3.3.x)](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1554).  However, the authors of Sass considered it to be a bug:

> The previous behavior was a bug. Variables should never have been allowed uninterpolated in any directives.

Comment: for @keyframes, its throwing me 'You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser' , how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Same as above with prefixes:

```
@mixin keyframes($animationName) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    $browser: '-webkit-' !global;
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    $browser: '-moz-' !global;
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes #{$animationName} {
    $browser: '-o-' !global;
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$animationName} {
    $browser: '' !global;
    @content;
  }
} $browser: null;
```

Full details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150621/sass-mixin-for-animation-keyframe-which-includes-multiple-stages-and-transform-p).

Or just use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) instead.